# Problem on using lxml with tostring and pretty_print

Tags: python, lxml, tostring, pretty-print

I have read some of the answers for related questions, but none of them is directly related with lxml tostring and pretty_print.

I am using lxml and trying to create a xml file on Python 3.6.

The problem I found is that elements are not wrapped and ordered by parent element and believe it is related with the "pretty_print" option.

What I need to achieve is:

```
<root>
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element2>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
</root>
```

The result I get is:

```
<root><element1></element1><element2></element2><child1></child1><child2></child2></root>
```

Part of the code I am using:

```
from lxml import etree as et

CompanyID = "Company Identification"
TaxRegistrationNumber = "Company Reg. Number"
TaxAccountingBasis = "File Tipe"                   
CompanyName = "Company Name"
BusinessName = "Business Name"

root = et.Element("root")
header = et.SubElement(root, 'Header')
header.tail = '\n'

data = (
       ('CompanyID', str(CompanyID)),
       ('TaxRegistrationNumber', str(TaxRegistrationNumber)),
       ('TaxAccountingBasis', str(TaxAccountingBasis)),
       ('CompanyName', str(CompanyName)),
       ('BusinessName', str(BusinessName)),
     )

for tag, value in data:
    if value is None :
        continue
    et.SubElement(header, tag).text=value

xml_txt = et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding="UTF-8")
print(xml_txt)
```

If I print the elements with no data into it, it works fine and the "pretty_print" works fine.

If I add data to each of the elements (using the above variables), the "pretty_print" does not work and the structure gets messed up.

What could be wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [mcve]. The code contains undefined variables such as `desiredvalue1`. And the indentation is bad.

Comment: The old code was just an example. The code runs fine and the identation was because of the copy/paste. Edited and added some real code. I am unable to post the result because the platform is changing the real result, but it starts with a "b'" and all elements with values at the same line with no "pretty_print" reformat

Comment: Sorry to be a nag, but I still cannot copy, paste and run your code.

Comment: Sorry me. I forgot to include the import at the top. Changed the code to be easier to copy and paste but the result is the same error on the output format

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

I have removed the "header.tail = '\n'" from the code and it's working now.

```
root = et.Element("root")
header = et.SubElement(root, 'Header')
#header.tail = '\n'
```

Thank you all